# Const Ref to const Pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am working with a library that I can't change and have been set a task to complete with the library.

Although I have done the task and it works,  I don't really understand why it works and whether I *should* do it.

I have a function in a cpp file

```
void Foo (const String &someName)
{
    OtherFoo (&someName)
}
```

where Foo passes a reference to a const string and OtherFoo requires a pointer to const string to be passed to it.

So basically ref is a `const string&` and needs to be passed into OtherFoo as a const pointer  (`const &` to `const *`)

Is what I've done OK?  (passing the address of the ref to the function that requires a pointer to const string)

Is there any negatives with how I have passed the argument?  Could someone explain exactly why it works?

Many thanks

Comment: (As for "vocabulary", `const foo *` is a pointer-to-const and not a const pointer (that would be `foo * const`), `const foo &` is a reference-to-const. Makes things less ambiguous.)

Comment: Thanks - have reworded for const correctness.  Please edit if you see any more.

Comment: Remember that `Foo` can be called with a temporary object and the lifetime of the temporary will be the call `Foo`. If `OtherFoo` stores the pointer for later use somewhere and that use happens after `Foo` is done, the pointer will point to a a dead object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct way of doing it. Indeed, taking the address of a reference yields in fact [the address of the referent](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs).

So in this case, the type of the expression `&someName` is actually `const String *`.

Be careful not to mix constness of the pointer and constness of the pointee though. In this case, when you say "const pointer", it's actually pointer to const which is not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited for const correctness.  if you see any other ambiguous statements of mine please feel free to edit them.